# Vaadin fetching the row of data on clicking of Individual button in a table

Tags: vaadin7

I created a table in vaadin and for each row I put a button i want to on click on each button the data of that row is to be shown but my problem is how I dynamically set the id (button.setData(**dynamicId**)) of each row in individual button and my second problem is for creating a button I make a method which i call everytime for creating the button but how I use this method for making clicklistiner for to identify which button is click

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using JPAContainer, so I can get the id in this way:
`

```
filterTable.addItemClickListener(new ItemClickEvent.ItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
        Product selectedProduct = (JPAContainerItem<Product>)event.getItem()).getEntity();
        ProductForm productForm = new ProductForm(....);
        ....
        }
    }
);
```

`
So, "event.getItem()" makes the magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a generated column where you create your Button and do something with the provided objects.

e.g.:

```
table.addGeneratedColumn("BUTTON_COLUMN", new ColumnGenerator() {

    @Override
    public Object generateCell(final Table source, final Object itemId, final Object columnId) {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                // do something with source; itemId; columnId like:
                // source.getContainerDataSource().removeItem(itemId);
            }
        });
        return button;
    }
});
```